# Python BertModel keeps throwing OutOfMemory

Tags: python, cluster-computing, bert-language-model

The following code was collected to cluster an access log. With a small amount of data, it runs fine. But when I use a pretty large log, the program keeps crashing. Is there any way to optimize the code?

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
import numpy as np
import torch
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
from collections import defaultdict

model_name = 'bert-base-uncased'
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = BertModel.from_pretrained(model_name)


def compute_text_similarity(texts1, texts2):
    encoded_inputs1 = tokenizer(texts1, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors='pt')
    encoded_inputs2 = tokenizer(texts2, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors='pt')

    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs1 = model(**encoded_inputs1)
        embeddings1 = outputs1.last_hidden_state[:, 0, :]

        outputs2 = model(**encoded_inputs2)
        embeddings2 = outputs2.last_hidden_state[:, 0, :]

    similarities = np.inner(embeddings1, embeddings2)
    return similarities


def group_similar_strings(strings):
    similarity_threshold = 0.9
    strings_mapping = {i: string for i, string in enumerate(strings)}
    strings_indices = list(strings_mapping.keys())

    similarities = compute_text_similarity(strings, strings)

    clustering = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=None, affinity='precomputed', linkage='complete',
                                         distance_threshold=1 - similarity_threshold)
    clusters = clustering.fit_predict(1 - similarities)

    groups = defaultdict(list)
    for i, cluster in enumerate(clusters):
        groups[cluster].append(strings_mapping[strings_indices[i]])

    return groups.values()


# log_lines = [
#     '40.77.167.129 - - [22/Jan/2019:03:56:17 +0330] "GET /image/23488/productModel/150x150 HTTP/1.1" 200 2654 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" "-"',
#     '40.77.167.129 - - [22/Jan/2019:03:56:18 +0330] "GET /image/45437/productModel/150x150 HTTP/1.1" 200 3688 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" "-"',
#     '40.77.167.129 - - [22/Jan/2019:03:56:18 +0330] "GET /image/576/article/100x100 HTTP/1.1" 200 14776 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" "-"',
#     '66.249.66.194 - - [22/Jan/2019:03:56:18 +0330] "GET /filter/b41,b665,c150%7C%D8%A8%D8%AE%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%BE%D8%B2,p56 HTTP/1.1" 200 34277 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" "-"',
#     '40.77.167.129 - - [22/Jan/2019:03:56:18 +0330] "GET /image/57710/productModel/100x100 HTTP/1.1" 200 1695 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" "-"',
#     '207.46.13.136 - - [22/Jan/2019:03:56:18 +0330] "GET /product/10214 HTTP/1.1" 200 39677 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" "-"',
#     '40.77.167.129 - - [22/Jan/2019:03:56:19 +0330] "GET /image/578/article/100x100 HTTP/1.1" 200 9831 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" "-"'
# ]

# opening the file in read mode
my_file = open("access.log", "r")
data = my_file.read()
log_lines = data.split("\n")

groups = group_similar_strings(log_lines[:1000])

for group in groups:
    print(group)
```

The log is around 3.5gb in size. So I tried to read 1000 lines to get around the memory error. Still it throws the same error. The traceback is attached also. The problem is, when I run the code, the C drive gets full and the program crashed. Tried running the code in google collab also, but it fails.

[image]

Comment: You could embed your lines one by one and then compute the similarity. However, I don't understand what does computing similarities and then clustering them would achieve. I think you want to cluster the logs, so you'd have to run `AgglomerativeClustering` on the embedded lines, am I missing something? If that's your intent, I think that would fail too. Because BERT embeddings would propably (didn't test this, just intuition) get diluted because of the IPs, timestamps, paths, etc.

Comment: **If** you want to implement a spam/ddos/hack detector,  I'd suggest collections samples and embedding them with BERT. Then you can compare incoming log with the known embeddings and make predictions whether they are harmful or not. Also, a vector database would make comparing the embeddings much faster.